Finding Killing vectors for hyperbolic space
I want to find the Killing vectors for the hyperbolic space, which is described by the metric
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = \frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2}.
\end{equation}
I have found the Killing equations, which result in the following three partial differential equations for the components $\xi_x$ and $\xi_y$ of the Killing vector field:

The $xx$ component:
\begin{equation}
   \partial_x \xi_x - \frac{1}{y} \xi_y = 0.
   \end{equation}

The $yy$ component:
\begin{equation}
   \partial_y \xi_y + \frac{1}{y} \xi_y = 0.
   \end{equation}

The $xy$ component:
\begin{equation}
   \partial_y \xi_x + \partial_x \xi_y + \frac{2}{y} \xi_x = 0.
   \end{equation}


From the second equation I get that
\begin{equation}
\xi_y=\frac{f(x)}{y}
\end{equation}
How do I proceed to solve them?

You're on the right track: The $(xx)$ equation will give $\xi_x=F(x)/y^2+g(y)$, and then the $(xy)$ gives a relation between $f'(x)$, $g(y)$ and $g'(y)$ that can only be solved for $f'(x)=\mathrm{const.}$, and then you end up with three free parameters (four actually, but two of them only enter the end result as a sum).

Something is wrong with your system of PDEs.
The Killing equation can be written as
$$\tag1
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Bigg|}V^k\,\partial_kg_{ij}+g_{jk}\,\partial_iV^k+g_{ik}\,\partial_jV^k=0\quad}
$$ See [1].
In your case,
$$\tag2
g_{xx}=g_{yy}=\frac 1{y^2}
\,,\quad \partial_y\,g_{xx}=\partial_y\,g_{yy}=-\frac 2{y^3}
$$
and all other components being zero. Therefore we have to solve
\begin{align}
\frac{-2V^y}{y^3}+\frac{2\partial_xV^x}{y^2}=0\,,\tag{$i=j=x$}\\[2mm]
\frac{-2V^y}{y^3}+\frac{2\partial_yV^y}{y^2}=0\,,\tag{$i=j=y$}\\[2mm]
\frac{\partial_xV^y+\partial_yV^x}{y^2}=0\,,\tag{$i=x,j=y$}
\end{align}
or more simply,
\begin{align}\tag3
-V^y+y\,\partial_xV^x&=0\,,&
-V^y+y\,\partial_yV^y&=0\,,&\partial_xV^y+\partial_yV^x=0\,.
\end{align}
From this elegant answer we find three Killing vector fields
$$\tag4
X_1=\partial_x\,,\quad X_2=x\,\partial_x+y\,\partial_y\,,\quad
X_3=(x^2-y^2)\,\partial_x+2xy\,\partial_y 
$$
that obviously solve the system (3). Cf. [2] where it is argued that
this is everything.
Edit. To settle a discussion what Lee's Killing equation (1) has to do with the one we often find in the literature:
$$\tag5
\boxed{\quad\phantom{\Bigg|}\nabla_iV_j+\nabla_jV_i=0\quad}
$$
where $\nabla_iV_j=\partial_iV_j-\Gamma^k_{ij}V_k$ and $V_j=g_{kj}V^k\,.$ Obviously,
\begin{align}\tag6
\nabla_iV_j=(\partial_ig_{kj})V^k+(\partial_iV^k)g_{kj}-\Gamma^k_{ij}V_k\,.
\end{align}
The last term can be written as
$$\tag7
\frac12g^{k\ell}\big(\partial_i g_{j\ell}+\partial_jg_{\ell i}-\partial_\ell g_{ij}\big)g_{m k}V^m=
\frac12\big(\partial_i g_{jk}+\partial_jg_{k i}-\partial_k g_{ij}\big)V^k\,.
$$
Then
\begin{align}\require{cancel}
\nabla_iV_j+\nabla_jV_i&=\cancel{(\partial_ig_{kj})V^k}+\bcancel{(\partial_jg_{ki})V^k}+(\partial_iV^k)g_{kj}+(\partial_jV^k)g_{ki}\\[2mm]
&\quad-\big(\cancel{\partial_i g_{jk}}+\bcancel{\partial_jg_{k i}}-\partial_k g_{ij}\big)V^k\tag8
\end{align}
which equals the LHS of (1). Therefore,

the Killing equations (1) are (5) equivalent and there cannot arise different sets of PDEs from them.

[1] J. Lee, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds.
[2] The Usual Suspect.

Although there may be some error in the relative sign in my equations, the killing equations I wrote are for the covariant components of the killing vector and the one in your answer gives the contravariant components, maybe because of that there is the difference?

Putting signs aside: I cannot find a PDE that corresponds to your third one,  $\partial_y \xi_x + \partial_x \xi_y + \frac{2}{y} \xi_x = 0,.$ Also: afaik vector fields are covariant and their components are mostly written with an upper index (Sean  Carroll's book for example). What is a contravariant Killing vector? I have no idea.

True, their components are written with upper indices but if you see the killing equations in terms of the covariant derivative, they are $\nabla_\mu \xi_\nu + \nabla_\nu \xi_\mu = 0$. So we can solve for $\xi_\mu$ and use the inverse of the metric tensor to get the components with the upper index.

So, the PDE $\partial_y \xi_x + \partial_x \xi_y + \frac{2}{y} \xi_x = 0$ , is obtained for $\mu=x$, $\nu=y$.

@HypnoticZebra see edit and conclusion in the bullet point the end.

put $i=x$ and $j=y$ in equation (i), we get another equation $g_{yy}\partial_x V^y + g_{xx} \partial_y V^x=0$.

I think you are right. Fortunately $X_1,X_2,X_3$ satisfy that equation. Need a break now and will edit later.
